# Get email keyboard instead of default keyboard for content editable div in iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic2

I have created an advance email input field with content editable div for my ionic2 app.
Is there any way to open the email key keyboard instead of default keyboard in iPhone devices ?

Answer (score -1):

In the interface builder, choose the keyboard type to be 'Email address'.
Else change the keyboard type via code as

```
inputField.keyboardType = emailAddress;
```